# QuickBooks API - Retrieve only data that has changed

Tags: api, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am building an app that accesses the QuickBooks API v2.

I am looking for a way to retrieve only data that has changed.

For example, from time to time want to be able to check to see if there have been any changes to the chart of accounts in the QB data. Is there a quick way to do this without parsing a large response body?  Maybe something like requesting and comparing just a checksum, and then requesting the whole chart of accounts to compare and update if there is a change?  Or even just requesting the changes that occurred after a certain date?

This need is not just limited to the chart of accounts.  For example, I may want to update historic transaction data, but only with the changes (e.g., a change to an old transaction), not the entire db which can be quite large.

**Answer**

In further reading the API docs, I should be able to filter the response using the created_at and updated_at metadata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filter is called Change Data Capture (CDC)

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0100_calling_data_services/0015_retrieving_objects

```
<ItemReceiptQuery xmlns='http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2'>
   <CDCAsOf>2010-12-04T09:30:47.0Z</CDCAsOf>
</ItemReceiptQuery>
```

thanks
Jarred